# Не компилируется, ошибка, хотя там её нету

Tags: c

Не работает программа, пишет "22  expected `;' before '{' token ", учусь через Dev-C++ 4.9, и в Far проверяю .exe, не понимаю, что происходит с ней. Помогите.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int counter = 1, number = 0, largest = 0, largest2 = 0;

    while (counter < 10)
    {
        printf("Enter number ");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if (number > largest) {
            largest = number;
            largest2 = largest;
        } else
            (number > largest2) {
            largest2 = number;
            }
        counter++;
    }

    printf("1 %dn", largest);
    printf("2 %dn", largest2);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как же нет ошибки, если есть:

```
else (number > largest2)
```

а, вероятно, нужно:

```
else if (number > largest2)
```

Comment: А можно объяснить почему такая конструкция не работает? Ведь синтаксически описано правильно.

Comment: Она просто не предусмотрена синтаксисом языка. Компилятор не знает, что значит `else` с последующим условием.

Comment: else if (number > largest2) - выдаёт подобные ошибки, ничего не меняется в лучшую сторону, я просто не могу понять как простейший пример не работает.

Comment: Пять минут назад тот же самый код с `else if (number > largest2)` без проблем скомпилировал. А "подобные ошибки" - это не конкретно. )

Comment: Спасибо дошло)

Answer (score 5):

Перед `main` поставьте `int`. 
И вместо `else` поставьте `else if`.

Comment: В C не требуется явное указание типа, возвращаемого `main`, хотя и является хорошим тоном.

Comment: А если я в конце помещу 
return "string"; 
компилятор это проглотит?

Comment: Не надо так делать

Comment: main() { return "string"; }

    qq.c(4): Warning! W304: Return type 'int' assumed for function 'main'
    qq.c(5): Warning! W102: Type mismatch (warning)
    qq.c(5): Note! N2003: source conversion type is 'char *'
    qq.c(5): Note! N2004: target conversion type is 'int '

Comment: А в Си я так понимаю для любых функций тип int считается типом по умолчанию?

Вот что говорит студия если определить функцию без возвращаемого типа:


error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию

Comment: Вообще-то по умолчанию возвращаемый тип int, так что можно и не указывать перед main, но вернуть что-нибудь можно.

Comment: Чем-то всё это напоминает забавы суровых сибирских мужиков с новой циркулярной пилой.

Comment: Ну так Россия же.

Comment: Изначально неправильно воспринял ответ.
Мне показалось, что если не указывать тип, то main ничего возвращать не станет то есть поставит void.

Comment: Могу посоветовать найти в и-нете книгу (есть и перевод) K&R с ещё старыми текстами (k&r, задолго до C89). Забавно сейчас на эти тексты посмотреть.

Comment: Вот эта?

Перевод:

Производственно-внедренческий кооператив
"И Н Т Е Р Ф Е Й С"

http://lib.ru/MAN/DEMOS210/c.txt

Comment: http://lib.ru/CTOTOR/kernigan.txt_with-big-pictures.html

Comment: @klopp Да. Только книга, которая у меня была не бумаге, содержала уже тексты маленькими буквами...

И, увы, качество сканирования/распознавания... "Массивы сруктур"...

Оно же -- http://chaos.ssu.runnet.ru/library/programms/progr/kr.pdf

Comment: Поискал ещё в электронном виде - везде большими :(

Comment: Ну значит у меня на бумаге было просто более позднее издание. А тут ещё и `\)` вместо фигурных скобок. Живьём я такого не видел.

Answer (score 1):

> А можно объяснить почему такая конструкция не работает? Ведь синтаксически описано правильно.

Если вы замените

```
if (number > largest) {
        largest = number;
        largest2 = largest;
    } else
        (number > largest2) {
        largest2 = number;
        }
```

на

```
if (number > largest) {
            largest = number;
            largest2 = largest;
        } else
            //(number > largest2) 
            {
            largest2 = number;
            }
```

то отработает нормально.

Если сделать так:

```
if (number > largest) {
        largest = number;
        largest2 = largest;
    } else
        int x = (number > largest2) {
        largest2 = number;
        }
```

то строчка `largest2 = number;` будет выполняться всегда, а `int x = (number > largest2)` только по условию.
`else` - это перевод безусловного "иначе", "в остальных вариантах"
для условия требуется "если": `else if`.
т.е. стандартная конструкция:

```
 if(a > b) {
     y = 1
 }
 else if(a < b) { 
     y = 0
 }
 else {// если a = b
     y = -1
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если добавить `;` после `(number > largest2)`, то компилируется. На самом деле, конечно, пропущен `if` в том месте, где компилятор ждет `;`.

С добавленной `;` и выравниванием  код выглядит так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
  int counter = 1, number = 0, largest = 0, largest2 = 0;

  while (counter < 10)
    {
      printf("Enter number ");
      scanf("%d", &number);

      if (number > largest) {
        largest = number;
        largest2 = largest;
      } else
        (number > largest2); 
      {
        largest2 = number;
      }
      counter++;
    }

  printf("1 %dn", largest);
  printf("2 %dn", largest2);
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

После добавления `;` *выражение* `(number > largest2)` превращается в оператор, а т.к. значение этого выражения ничему не присваивается, то оператор становится "пустым" и его (вместе с `else`) можно выбросить. В результате получаем код эквивалентный такому:

```
  while (counter < 10) {
    printf("Enter number ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if (number > largest) {
      largest = number;
      largest2 = largest;
    }

    largest2 = number;
    counter++;
  }
```

Синтаксически правильно, но бессмысленно (в `largest2` будет последнее из введенных чисел).

Comment: @avp, Я уже понял ошибки и переделал, спасибо)

Comment: Да это просто пояснение к тому, что Вы видели и что бы получилось, если просто вставить `;`.